# converting JSON ARRAY into NSnumber Array

Tags: ios, arrays, json, core-plot, type-conversion

I used the following code to save data received from JSON into an array.

```
for (int i =1 ; i<[json count];i++)
{
    [_datearray addObject:[[json objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Date"]];
    [_soldarray addObject:[[json objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"SoldAmount"]];
}
```

I am not sure what type of data type this saves in, is there a way to save one array as a NSdate array and the other as a NSnumber Array. because I am using core plot with these two arrays but the data won't plot because it is in a different format? I created a simple array:

```
NSArray *prices;
prices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
          [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:0],
          [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:1],
          [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:1],
          [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:2],
          [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:3],
          nil];
```

and the data plots out fine. so I am quite sure it is the data type issue. but I could be wrong. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't use `valueForKey:`, use `objectForKey:`. And your simple array can be done as follows using modern syntax: `NSArray *prices = @[ @0, @1, @1, @2, @3 ];` - though that gives `NSNumber`, not `NSDecimalNumber`.

Comment: I believe valueForKey will return NSStrings. You need to convert the strings to nsdate and nsdecimal objects

Comment: @Hackmodford `valueForKey:` will return whatever the data is, not just `NSString`. Or it could return an `NSArray` if there are multiple values.

Comment: JSON does not deal in NSDate objects -- you need to convert.  The problem is, you've given us no clue as to how date is represented, so we can't tell you what to do.  Show us a snippet of the source JSON.

Comment: SoldAmount could be returned as either a char string or an NSNumber.  Date would likely be returned as either a formatted date such as "2013-12-12" (in an NSString) or a "Unix epoch" value which is seconds since Jan 1 1970.  This latter would be a number something like 1389403553, returned as an NSNumber.

Comment: To tell what kind of value you have do `NSLog(@"The class is %@", [theValue class]);`

Comment: _soldarray : {0, 0, 0, "62.69", "48.3", 81,}
_datearray : {("02/07/12", "02/10/12", "02/14/12", "02/11/12", "02/10/12", "02/12/12"}

snippet of the data received

Comment: @rmaddy , i've changed valueForKey to objectForKey, but it's still failing to plot.

Comment: So both values are delivered as strings rather than numbers.  To convert the dates (if you want them as NSDates) you need to use an NSDateFormatter. @bret kind of has the idea, though he got the format string wrong.

Comment: thank you @HotLicks , I am now having trouble converting the JSON string into NSNumbers. how can i do this??

Comment: NSNumber *num = [[json objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"SoldAmount"] ;[_soldarray addObject:num];

Comment: ^ i tried that but it did not solve my problem

Comment: JSON returns numbers either as NSNumbers or as NSStrings.  In your case, given that the numbers are surrounded by quotes in the original JSON, they're NSStrings.  To get the numbers, since they're possibly floating point, do `double num = [[[json objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"SoldAmount"] doubleValue];`.

Comment: (You can also convert the NSString retrieved from the converted JSON to an NSDecimalNumber, if you want to preserve decimal precision: `NSDecimalNumber num = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[[json objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"SoldAmount"]];`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the date being returned from JSON is in string format you will need a data formatter to convert the json string into an NSDate.

// some where in interface declaration

```
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSDateFormatter * _dateFormatter_en_US_POSIX;
```

Then add methods to class

```
    /** create a date formatter to send data to a JSON consumer
     *
     */
    - (NSDateFormatter *)dateFormatterForjsonDateStringFromNSDate
    {
        if (_dateFormatter_en_US_POSIX){
            return _dateFormatter_en_US_POSIX;
        }
        _dateFormatter_en_US_POSIX = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
        [_dateFormatter_en_US_POSIX setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'"];
        [_dateFormatter_en_US_POSIX setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
        [_dateFormatter_en_US_POSIX setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
        return _dateFormatter_en_US_POSIX;
    }

-(NSDate*) dateWithJSONString:( NSString*) dateStr
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [self dateFormatterForjsonDateStringFromNSDate];
    return [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
}
```

Then change:

```
 [_datearray addObject:[[json objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Date"]];
```

To:

```
 [_datearray addObject:[self dateWithJSONString:[[json objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Date"]]];
```

Comment: Wrong dateFormat -- should be "MM/dd/yy".

Comment: My data is stored in mongodb.  The data is put there via mongoosejs in my nodejs application.  The JSON formatted date look like this:reedited (String) =  2014-01-11T02:41:37.684Z   Why do you suggest MM/DD/YY?

Comment: Because, based on the comment by the OP, the incoming data is "MM/dd/yy" (which is *not* the same as "MM/DD/YY").  And the format needs to match the data it will be reading.